# Read Item in Queue<T> before Dequeueing

Tags: c#, .net, generics, .net-3.5, queue

I have a `Queue<T>`

In my `T` I have a DateLoaded property.

I want to say if the DateLoaded is older than 5 minutes dequeue it and execute code on `T`

Is this possible?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Use the [`Peek()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1cz28y5c.aspx) method.

Answer (score 1):

You can call `Peek` to look at what the first element in the queue is.